# Reading files from Documents directory using xcode

Tags: xcode, nsarray, nspredicate, nsbundle

with reference to my own question,
[UITable is not getting populated with NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091810/uitable-is-not-getting-populated-with-nsmutablearray)  here i got all the file names into a table. And these files where stored in 'Resources' folder. Now i need to fill the same table from the files stored in a subfolder say 'sample' which is in documents folder of ios simulator. 
Earlier i did this with the following code

```
files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
     [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:nil];
search_results_array = [files filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self BEGINSWITH[cd] 'h'"]];
```

here both files and search_results_array are arrays. Now the reading is not from resources. How can i edity it? anybody please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //Library directory is not accessible via iTunes, Document directory is
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    path = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourString]; //3
    files = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

Assuming files is an NSDictionary.